# null key in from map/reduce result in couchdb

Tags: dictionary, couchdb, reduce, couchapp

For some reason I'm only getting a null key from map/reduce result in couchdb on mac

Result:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":2224}
]}
```

Im using couchapp v8.1 and couchdb v1.0.2

My map function is:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.doc_type, 1);
}
```

My reduce function is:

```
function(key, values, rereducer) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

result I was expecting:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"type1","value":22}
{"key":"type2","value":32}
{"key":"type3","value":25}
 //snip snip
]}
```

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just to save newbies the pain I've been through to get to this answer,
please look at the `group` parameter of [the _view API](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/main/api/ddoc/views.html) which is explained in more detail in [the CouchDB guide](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/main/ddocs/views/intro.html#the-view-to-get-comments-for-posts).

I just add `?group=true` to my url, and the reduce result was grouped as expected
the default behavior is that reduce will spit out a single value.

Comment: +1 Good advice! I find myself always adding `?reduce=false` even if I don't have a reduce function, just to be sure.

Comment: @jhs: FWIW, `?reduce=false` used to break when no reduce function was defined, back in 0.11 (I'm glad it was solved).

Comment: Don't understand it's not in the default query... Also is not mentioned in the doc.couchbase.com...

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: Day saver. Thanks!